# How to make the whole <canvas> element in Chart.js V3.7.0 display cursor as pointer on hover?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3

how can I make my `canvas` element display cursor style as `pointer` when I hover over it.

**HTML**:

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

I tried both:

```
events: ['mousemove', 'click'],
onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
  event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}
```

And:

```
options: {
  plugins : {
    legend: {   
      labels: {
        onHover: function (e) {
          e.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        },
        onLeave: function (e) {
          e.native.target.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But had no luck.

**Pictures:**

[image]

All in all, I want the cursor to have style equal to pointer on whole chart, and not just on the red points in the picture. (Red point with Yellow arround it, is an example of point I want my cursor to look like a pointer.).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you do it with CSS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor in particular, e.g. `<canvas id="myChart" style="cursor:crosshair"></canvas>`

Comment: @tevemadar I dont think the OP is looking for crosshair because  he says "style equal to pointer".

Comment: He can look at the linked page for what's available, crosshair was just an example @VarunW.

Comment: @LeeLenalee Yeap, that was excactly the callback I was looking for. Both ways worked Perfectly. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSS, you need `canvas:hover{cursor: pointer}`. The `canvas:hover` will run the code inside when the cursor is hovering over the element. The `cursor: pointer` will tell the cursor to become a pointer. For more information, go [here for other cursor types](http://w3schools.com/csSref/pr_class_cursor.asp) and [here for hover selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Or if you don't have a CSS file, you can do this: `<canvas id="myChart" style="cursor: pointer"></canvas>` . That will do the same thing as explained above.

Comment: You don't really need the ":hover" qualifier, as "cursor" only applies when the cursor (on a non-touch device) is over the element; it's inherently for "hover" situations.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: @Pointy yes but some out of date machines and operating systems still need `canvas:hover`. But most ones like Safari Chrome Firefox and many more have it default. I still recommend most people using `canvas:hover` because it is a very small line of code which can only benefit the user's experience.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same effect, but using javascript? or perhaps using chart.js's built in functions for callbacks or anything else?

Comment: Could you add your full javascript and css code in the original post.